# MySQL help: How to find all orders from a customer till sum(price) <= 150 and status='unpaid'

Tags: mysql

Example:

```
select orderid
from `orders`
where sum(price) <= 150 and status=unpaid and ownerid=110786
```

but it didn't work.

Detail:
I want to find all orders from a customer (ownerid) where status is UNPAID up to (price) 150.

This is required because I want to allow the customers to pay for as much orders as much they can from available funds.

---

**For ANSWER No.1** 
may work as expected but there is some mistake in the code as it is not generating the required result and when I also added TotalSoFar to see if the value is working all lines are showing their double price in this field instead of last-column-price+current-column-price values. I am not sure my details are making sense but I am just trying to illustrate what mysql is returing as result :)

**For ANSWER No.2** 
you wrote status instead of paymentstatus so the result was blank but when I corrected that and ran following query:

select orderid, price, designname from orders where paymentstatus='unpaid' and ownerid=110786 group by orderid having sum(price) <= 50

```
RESULT SHOWN IS: 

orderid price   designname 
114279  15  Premier Academy    
114280  10  Troop              
114386  15  Texas Tennis 
114408  20  Nokia Developer   
114508  15  Gold  Lighthouse
```

AS YOU CAN SEE PRICE TOTAL IS NOT LESS THAN $50 but $75. PLEASE HELP... THANKS!

**Also Mods please note that stackoverflow is a wonderful service but formatting the comments is a real tough job. Please make it easy somehow. I tried too many times to format the comments in a way that it can be read easily but all efforts failed so now I am writing the comments in answering my question area**

However, this question is not answered correctly till now. Although good people are trying their best to help me. I have re-posted this question again as for too long nobody came with a workable solution but the new question is also not being answered with a working solution :)

Please guys help me somehow. What i am trying to do is a general kind of thing all carts do one way or another. If a customer has 10 orders for $10 each totaling to $100 but he has only $50.00. How can he check that how many orders can be paid with this amount? This is all what I need to find/code.

Comment: you may need quotes if "unpaid" is a string

Comment: what is it giving you? an error? the wrong dataset?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can accomplish this with MySQL variables... use one as a running total and apply a HAVING clause to cut it off...

```
select
      o.orderid,
      o.price,
      @RunningTotal := @RunningTotal + o.price as TotalSoFar
   from
      orders o,
      ( select @RunningTotal := 0 ) sqlvars
   where
          o.ownerid = 110786
      and o.status = unpaid
   having 
      TotalSoFar <= 150
```

The @RunningTotal variable just keeps getting added to "on-the-fly" and is stuck in a final column for the query result, but remains as just a variable for the next record that qualifies the WHERE clause.  So, even if you have orders that total up to 200, 300, whatever, the final HAVING clause will cut those off by using the "TotalSoFar" column as basis to remove all the other rows...

Comment: The above two answers are not working as required :(
  
PLEASE HELP.

Comment: @HaiderAbbas, how not working... crash in SQL? not proper result? Can you show some sample data of what you have vs what the result is coming up with?  Not working is like saying I need a rock and don't describe what kind of rock I need.

Answer (score 0):

it's unclear if you're getting an error but try this:

```
select orderid
from `orders`
where status=unpaid and ownerid=110786
group by orderid
having sum(price) <= 150
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT FOR TRYING TO HELP but it is neither giving any error nor showing anything. Just a blank orderid field. Please advise.

Comment: what do you get when you try "select * from orders where ownerid=110786 and status=unpaid"?

Comment: you wrote status instead of paymentstatus so the result was blank but when I correct that I ran:

select orderid, price, designname 
from `orders`
where paymentstatus='unpaid' and ownerid=110786 
group by orderid having sum(price) <= 50


RESULT SHOWN IS:

orderid price designname
114279 15 Premier Academy
114280 10 Troop 32
114386 15 Texas Tennis
114408 0 Schnauzer Club
114409 0 Schnauzer Club_2
114434 20 Nokia Developer
114508 15 Gold Lighthouse

AS YOU CAN SEE PRICE TOTAL IS NOT LESS THAN $50 but $75. PLEASE HELP... THANKS!

Comment: <pre>
you wrote status instead of paymentstatus so the result was blank but when I correct that I ran:  
  
select orderid, price, designname   
from `orders`   
where paymentstatus='unpaid' and ownerid=110786   
group by orderid having sum(price) <= 50   
   
  
RESULT SHOWN IS:  
  
orderid price designname  
114279 15 Premier Academy  
114280 10 Troop 32  
114386 15 Texas Tennis  
114408 0 Schnauzer Club  
114409 0 Schnauzer Club_2  
114434 20 Nokia Developer  
114508 15 Gold Lighthouse  
  
AS YOU CAN SEE PRICE TOTAL IS NOT LESS THAN $50 but $75. PLEASE HELP... THANKS!  
</pre>

Comment: please update your original post - it's hard to read this in the comments

Comment: you wrote status instead of paymentstatus so the result was blank but when I correct that I ran: 
  
select orderid, price, designname from orders where paymentstatus='unpaid' and ownerid=110786 group by orderid having sum(price) <= 50 
 
` RESULT SHOWN IS: 
  
orderid price designname 
114279 15 Premier Academy    
114280  10 Troop              
114386 15 Texas Tennis 
114408 20 Nokia Developer   
114508 15 Gold  Lighthouse 
`  
AS YOU CAN SEE PRICE TOTAL IS NOT LESS THAN $50 but $75. PLEASE HELP... THANKS!

Comment: For all who are looking for the answer to this question. THE ANSWER TO THIS QUESTION (Provided by DRapp) CAN BE FOUND AT THE FOLLOWING LINK:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560839/mysql-help-how-to-find-all-orders-from-a-customer-till-price-20-and-status/9560996#comment12143297_9560996

  
Thanks DRapp for all your help. I really appreciate it. Your solution/answer is working 100% same as required by me.