# MySQL help: How to find all orders from a customer till price <= 20 and status='unpaid'

Tags: mysql, product, orders

I think my question will be understood better by providing the following example:

i have a table with following data:

```
orderid  Price username paymentstatus
1        10    john     unpaid
2        10    john     unpaid
4        10    john     unpaid
5        10    john     unpaid
6        10    sam      unpaid
7        10    john     unpaid
8        10    john     paid
```

I want to find all orders of (username) john where paymentstatus is "unpaid" and price total is <= 20

So the result should show following 2 lines (as order total is $20 and payment status is unpaid and username is john)

```
EXPECTED RESULT:
==
orderid  Price username paymentstatus
1        10    john     unpaid  
2        10    john     unpaid

==
```

I hope you got my point/question?

Please help.. Thanks!

Comment: The price total <=20 is ambiguous. You must mention exactly what orders should be taken into account

Comment: price total is not a mysql field.  I want mysql to calculate column price and stop showing results when price total (result of calulation) is 20. So it must show not more than 2 results in above example.

Comment: why dont u consider adding another column which calculates the total of prices for all orders before itself. This way writing the query will be easier. U will just need to print all the records whose total price ( the new column) is less than 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost EXACT [same question answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962104/mysql-help-how-to-find-all-orders-from-a-customer-till-sumprice-150-and-st/7965812#7965812).  The premise is you would need another column to act as a running total for the customer in question...

I created table and simulated data exactly like your results and came up with YOUR exact results...  The issue was somehow MySQL was applying the criteria TWICE per row and didn't understand how or why... I STRONGLY suspect its a bug, but can't describe it.  Anyhow, I DO have a fix that forces an inner "PreQuery" as the basis, and return ALL records from that with the @SQLVars and then apply a WHERE clause from that...

```
select properSummed.*
   from 
      ( select
              o.orderid, 
              o.price, 
              @RunningTotal := @RunningTotal + o.price as UnpaidSoFar
           from
              orders o, 
              (select @RunningTotal := 0 ) sqlvars
           where o.ownerid = 1
             and o.paymentstatus = 'unpaid' ) properSummed
    where 
       properSummed.UnpaidSoFar <= 50
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, that question was also posted by be and I am still looking for an answer. The answers posted to that question were not working and nobody else replied for so long so i posted the question again to see if now anyone can answer it. Please help.

Comment: @HaiderAbbas, Yes, I knew it was your original question, but I never saw response from your test of my query... did you get error?  what DID it return?

Comment: I have ran your suggestion on the previous question again on the actual table to show you the results. I will post them as answer to make the text readable in easy formatting. The problem is that TotalSoFar values are not correct. For example: if there are $50 worth of orders and I select TotalSoFar => 50 then it returns only $25 worth of orders (half the price) and hide all the rest. I also tried doubling the required amount but then it returned $60.00 worth of orders. I will post the query exactly as I ran and the actual test result below as my answer. Please check & help me. Thanks!

Comment: THANKS A LOT DRapp, you are wonderful. I have marked the answer as correct. It finally worked as expected. Can you please confirm that this query may or may not put any extra load on mysql server or generate any extra log files? I hope this code is okay to be used for heavy/large databases.

Comment: @HaiderAbbas, I don't think it will cause any extra as you are doing a very finite query for a singler person per set... of that set, how many will actually be "unpaid".  So the inner query will get the results almost instantaneously, and then use that as basis to just "exclude" those past your limit.

Comment: @ DRapp, thank you for the confirmation. A user normally has >500 orders in a month but I was concerned what if 5 or 6 of them attempt to pay at the same time as we have a lot of customers. However, the code is working very good/quickly so far so I don't think there will be any problems. Cheers! Many thanks for all the help provided by you and do feel free to let me know if I can be of any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this?

```
SELECT *
FROM order_table
WHERE username = 'john' 
AND paymentstatus = 'unpaid'
AND Price <= 20
```

But given your criteria, I would expect the results to also include orders 4, 5 and 7.

Comment: No sorry, this returned all orders that have price less than or equal to 20 but the total of all those orders is far more than 20. I want mysql to calculate price and stop showing results when price total is 20.

Comment: Then you actually need to state that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
select *
from `orders`
where paymentstatus='unpaid' and username='john'
having sum(price) <= 20
```

Comment: It lists all orders not just 2 of them as if we calculate the price of first 2 orders, the price total will be $20.00 but it is listing $75.00 worth of orders.

Comment: occording to the table you created there is no way products sum 75$us, because all fields come with a price of 10$us.

Comment: Yes you are right, the price is showing as $70 not $75. Typing mistake. Thanks!