# Complicated Query

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure if the following can be done using a mere select statement, but I have two tables (truncated with the data necessary to the problem).

**Inventory Item**

- id *int* (PRIMARY)
- quantity *int*

**Stock** - Contains changes in the stock of the inventory item (stock history)

- id *int* (PRIMARY)
- inventory_item_id *int* (FOREIGN KEY)
- quantity *int*
- created *datetime*

**The *quantity* in stock is the change in stock, while the quantity in inventory item is the current quantity of that item**

EVERYTHING IN THE `running` COLUMN WILL RETURN 0

```
SELECT
inventory_item.id,
(inventory_item.quantity - SUM(stock.quantity)) AS running
FROM
    stock
        JOIN
    inventory_item ON stock.inventory_item_id = inventory_item.id
GROUP BY inventory_item.id
```

**THE QUESTION**

Now, what I would like to know is: Is it possible to select all of the dates in the stock table where the running quantity of the inventory_item ever becomes zero using a SELECT?

I know this can be done programmatically by simply selecting all of the stock data in one item, and subtracting the stock quantity individually from the current inventory item quantity, which will get the quantity before the change in stock happened.  Can I do this with a SELECT?

Comment: Will there ever be more than one record for a given combination of inventory_item_id and created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My take on it:

```
select
    inventory_item_id `item`,
    created `when`
from
    (select 
         @total := CASE WHEN @curr <> inventory_item_id
                   THEN quantity
                   ELSE @total+quantity END as running_total,
         inventory_item_id,
         created,                   
         @curr := inventory_item_id
     from
         (select @total := 0) a
         (select @curr  := -1) b
         (select inventory_item_id, created, quantity from stock order by inventory_item_id, created asc) c
     ) running_total
where running_total.running_total = 0;
```

This one has the relative advantage of having to give only one pass to the stock table. Depending on the size and the indexes on it that may or may not be a good thing.

Answer (score 5):

(Updated) Assuming there will never be more than one record for a given combination of inventory_item_id and created, try:

```
SELECT i.id,
       s.created,
       i.quantity - COALESCE(SUM(s2.quantity),0) AS running
FROM inventory_item i
JOIN stock s ON s.inventory_item_id = i.id
LEFT JOIN stock s2 ON s2.inventory_item_id = i.id and s.created < s2.created
GROUP BY i.id, s.created
HAVING running=0
```

Comment: Since i.quantity is the latest quantity, this is incorrect.  I think you need to change your `running` field to `SUM(s2.quantity)`.  Then this will return the correct results for all stock dates, not just the latest.

Comment: @Tom: I have amended the query to take into account the point you raised. It would be incorrect to use the sum of the `stock.quantity` alone as the running total, as it is used to hold *changes* in quantities held in stock - summing it would tell us how much change there had been, but not what the stock level was at the time.

Comment: I was assuming the sum of the stock.quantity was the running total because he said: "The quantity in stock is the change in stock, while the quantity in inventory item is the current quantity of that item

EVERYTHING IN THE running COLUMN WILL RETURN 0".  Perhaps I am interpreting this wrong?  I figured the first entry in the stock table would be the beginning stock.

Comment: The way you have it would work if there is, or is not a complete stock history.  So it's probably the safest way to go unless you know you have a full stock history.

Answer (score 2):

The most logical way to do this is with a cumulative sum.  But, MySQL doesn't support that.

The clearest approach, in my opinion, is to use a correlated subquery to get the running quantity.  Then it is a simple matter of a `where` clause to select where it is `0`:

```
select i.*
from (select i.*,
             (select SUM(i2.inventory)
              from inventory i2
              where i2.inventory_item_id = i.inventory_item_id and
                    i2.created <= i.created
             ) as RunningQuantity
      from inventory i
     ) i
 where RunningQuantity = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a simple approach to this.

```
SELECT inventory_item.id, stock.created

FROM   inventory_item

       JOIN stock ON stock.inventory_item_id = inventory_item.id

WHERE  (SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM stock WHERE created <= stock.created) = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a response similar based on a running total to be flagged [found here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560839/mysql-help-how-to-find-all-orders-from-a-customer-till-price-20-and-status/9560996#9560996)

You can do with MySQL @variables, but the data needs to be pre-queried and ordered by the data of activity... then set a flag on each row that causes the negative and keep only those.  Something like

```
select 
      PreQuery.*
   from 
      ( select
              s.id,
              s.created,
              @runBal := if( s.id = @lastID, @runBal - quantity, @i.quantity ) as CurBal,
              @lastID := s.id as IDToCompareNextEntry
           from
              stock s
                 join inventory_item ii
                    on s.inventory_item_id = ii.id,
              (select @lastID := -1,
                      @runBal := 0 ) sqlvars
           order by
              s.id,
              s.created DESC ) PreQuery
   where
      PreQuery.CurBal < 0
```

This way, for each inventory item, it works backwards by created date (order by the created descending per ID).  So, when the inventory ID changes, look to the inventory table "Quantity" field to START the tally of used stock down.  If same ID as the last record processed, just use the running balance and subtract out the quantity of that stock entry.